# parse a line with special characters, digits, spaces and get a part of it using regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to parse lines which looks like:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.3.2   2  
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.4.1   64      127.0.0.101
```

I use the below code to parse it:

```
while {[gets $in line] != -1} {
    
     regexp {(.*\.)\d+} $line -> line 
     puts "$line \n" }
```

in this case i get

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.3.       ---> I don't want to hold the "." at the end
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.4.1   64      127.0.0. -----> it holds also the whole string with values    and remove only the last dgits after the last dot.
```

how can modify the regexp so as to take the below reults:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.3 
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
regexp {^(\S+)\.\d+} $line -> line
```

See the [Tcl demo online](https://ideone.com/OeF3KT).

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+)` - Group 1 (its contents are assigned to `line`): one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Hl6IA/1).

Answer (score 0):

A non-regexp version for comparison:

```
while {[gets $in line] >= 0} {
    set word [lindex [split $line] 0]
    puts [string range $word 0 [string last . $word]-1]
}
```